# Ember best practices for maintaining the integrity of identifiers

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Let's say I have some simple template code...

```
{{#if prop}}
    <h1>Hi!</h1>
{{/if}}
```

...with a corresponding controller...

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    prop: true
});
```

After some time, I might decide that I need to change the name of the property in the controller, for whatever reason. I change the name of 'prop' to 'newProp' in the controller.

Now if I forget to change the expression in the template, I have a problem. If I understand correctly, Ember won't throw an error if no property of that name exists on the associated controller/model. This is "by design" if I understand correctly, however in such cases could lead to regression.

My question is: what are the "best practices" to avoid these kind of integrity issues? Are there development tools that will highlight such problems? Is there an option to log such occurrences in Ember's debug mode (couldn't see any [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/))? Is there an option to force Ember to blow up in these cases (e.g. some hook that lets me tap into the property/expression-resolution logic)? Or is it left to things like integration testing to check that handlebars expressions are doing what is expected?

Motivation: as an Ember newbie, I find I'm refactoring a LOT in these early stages. I'd like some kind of nice "safety net" so that I know that all template expressions continue to resolve to something defined after I make these refactorings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, making sure that your templates are rendering everything they are supposed to is done with integration tests.

To verify that property resolution and business logic is correct you add unit tests for your controllers.

I'm sure you already have seen this, but I'm adding this link just in case: http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/

Comment: Cheers for your input. We have Ember integration testing in place, based on the guide you linked. I guess we'll just have to make sure our integration tests have full coverage in order to avoid such problems.